# using a coil for an electrochemical reaction

Tags: electrical-engineering, chemical-engineering, electromagnetism

I wish to calculate the amount of energy required for electrolysis through induction, instead of electrodes. If there is a crucible metal core 
with solution inside and the coil wrapped around it. Can there be the required voltage for the electrolysis reaction and enough current to transport the ions? 
If I have the resistance of the solution inside the crucible (derived from its resistivity of an area) and the voltage produced from the inductor will this tell me how much current is flowing through the solution and then inturn allow me to calculate Faradays laws? 
Not really asking for a solution more the correct steps to get there.
Thank you for taking the time to read the question.

Comment: Electrolysis typically requires electrodes and a voltage field. Do you have an example of  such a field generated from an induction coil?

Comment: In chemistry they say you can induce an electrical flux for an electrochemical response.

Comment: The problem is that sustained induced fields generally need to be AC, unless you've found a practical way to induce a DC field. Electrochemical reactions are generally reversible, so applying an AC field has no permanent effect.

Comment: Even with a steady electric field, this should just align the charged particles with the field. The electrodes supply and remove electrons in addition to supplying a potential.